# .NET CF set 'DroppedDown' for combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, compact-framework

I want to open a combobox from my program on a mobile program (.net cf 3.5).

but there doesn't exist a property like `cmbBox.DroppedDown` in compact-framework
[Accesing WinCE ComboBox DroppedDown property (.NET CF 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853847/accesing-wince-combobox-droppeddown-property-net-cf-2-0)
But I don't want to get the current state, but to set it.

How do I perform this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the same approach as in the referenced article and send it a Message.

Instead use `const int CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = 0x14F` for your message.

From that reference sample, modified a bit:

```
Message.Create(comboBox.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN , (IntPtr)1, IntPtr.Zero); // to open

Message.Create(comboBox.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN , (IntPtr)0, IntPtr.Zero); // to close
```

Comment: where should  I place this code to take effect? I have placed this code in MyForm_Load event after combobox.SelectIndex = 0; combobox.Focus(); and this code has no effect.

Comment: The code snippet above was the modification required to make the referenced article (the one in the question) perform the desired behavior.  You'd need to review that one as well.

Answer (score 7):

Use `CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = 0x014F` message:

```
    public const int CB_GETDROPPEDSTATE = 0x0157;
    public static bool GetDroppedDown(ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        Message comboBoxDroppedMsg = Message.Create(comboBox.Handle, CB_GETDROPPEDSTATE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        MessageWindow.SendMessage(ref comboBoxDroppedMsg);
        return comboBoxDroppedMsg.Result != IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    public const int CB_SHOWDROPDOWN = 0x014F;
    public static bool ToogleDropDown(ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        int expand = GetDroppedDown(comboBox) ? 0 : 1;
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(new Int32());
        IntPtr pBool = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.WriteInt32(pBool, 0, expand);  // last parameter 0 (FALSE), 1 (TRUE)
        Message comboBoxDroppedMsg = Message.Create(comboBox.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, pBool, IntPtr.Zero);
        MessageWindow.SendMessage(ref comboBoxDroppedMsg);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBool);
        return comboBoxDroppedMsg.Result != IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit more improved :

```
public bool ToogleDropDown()
{
    int expand = GetDroppedDown() ? 0 : 1;
    //int size = Marshal.SizeOf(new Int32());
    //IntPtr pBool = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    //Marshal.WriteInt32(pBool, 0, expand);  // last parameter 0 (FALSE), 1 (TRUE)
    Message comboBoxDroppedMsg = Message.Create(this.Handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, (IntPtr)expand, IntPtr.Zero);
    MessageWindow.SendMessage(ref comboBoxDroppedMsg);
    //Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBool);
    return comboBoxDroppedMsg.Result != IntPtr.Zero;
}
```